# Chrome custom tabs not working correctly with CustomTabsIntent

Tags: android, google-chrome, chrome-custom-tabs

I've been trying to explore the *Google Chrome custom tabs* tool but something is intriguing me.

Using the following version of the library on Android Studio

```
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.2.0'
```

and then running a sample using the `CustomTabsIntent` isn't working as I expected.

```
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder(customTabActivityHelper.getSession())
                        .setCloseButtonIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_action_back))
                        .setToolbarColor(Color.RED)
                        .addDefaultShareMenuItem()
                        .build();
CustomTabActivityHelper.openCustomTab(getActivity(), customTabsIntent, Uri.parse(url), null);
```

Using this, only the `setToolbarColor()` is working. The `setCloseButtonIcon()`,  `addDefaultShareMenuItem()` or even other instructions are not taking any effect.

Has anybody experienced something like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two different reason:

- `setCloseButtonIcon`

  probably doesn't work because the bitmap you use
  has the wrong dimensions. As documented by
  [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent.html#KEY_ICON):

  > Key that specifies the Bitmap to be used as the image source for the
  >   action button. The icon should't be more than 24dp in height (No
  >   padding needed. The button itself will be 48dp in height) and have a
  >   width/height ratio of less than 2.

  You can get the correct *back arrow* bitmap from the [custom-tabs-client](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/tree/master/Application/src/main/res) repo.
- `addDefaultShareMenuItem`

  As you can see on [chromium.org](https://codereview.chromium.org/1509713004) the default share button is a newly added feature and it
  currently works only with [Chrome Beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.beta) and [Chrome Dev](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.dev). You need to wait that [Chrome Stable](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome) will be updated with this feature, in the meantime this parameter will be ignored on the stable version.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much.